# ODATA Site Offline

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

Is odata.stackexchange.com offline for a data refresh, or is it dead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Data Explorer appears to have moved to https://data.stackexchange.com/

A [post about this change](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/12/re-launching-stack-exchange-data-explorer/) was published on the Stack Overflow blog.

Comment: so it does. Shame there is not a 302 redirect from the old site. Most of the links in the meta are probably out of date now!

Comment: Live data, awesome!

Comment: Just to confirm this is not some temporary thing: the links in the footers have dropped the leading "o" too.

Comment: @Arjan, you're right, it is behind by a day or two.  Well past the last data dump, this must have been fed from the main dbase.  I reckon the About page was just copied from odata.  A couple of days will tell, maybe even a blog post :)

Comment: @Hans, I guess you might just have been lucky to look at the site soon after a new import? Today its `most recent` column still shows the same dates as a week ago (being December 3rd up to 8th). To be continued ;-)

Comment: Ah, @Hans, now I am sure. According to [the FAQ](http://data.stackexchange.com/faq): *At the moment it is updated shortly after every Stack Exchange Creative Commons Data Dump.* Indeed, no changes in the dates since December 12th.

Answer (score 6):

There was a missing redirect, the old urls to odata.stackexchange.com should redirect permanently to data.stackexchange.com

This was part of a big migration off Azure.

Comment: Do we get full-text indexes on the post bodies now? :)

Comment: @Jon, sure ... it just that this proc needs to be amended :) http://goo.gl/eDIRm

Comment: Is that a hint? ;) Come to think of it, I could add a PostTypes table while I'm at it.

Comment: @Jon ... it sure is :) it would be nice to see some awesome contributions to poor old SEDE

Comment: Argh... I don't have VS2010 at home. I will see what I can do with that SQL script, though.

Comment: Note on OData: maybe work in progress, and I'm not using/don't know OData endpoints, but I wonder if the FAQ is still correct? It claims "Yes, on the front page there are links to the OData endpoints" and I do see things like `<link rel="odata.service" title="StackOverflow" href="/stackoverflow/atom"/>` in the HTML. Maybe things like http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom are not supposed to work with a GET from a plain browser? I kind of doubt that though.

Comment: yeah @Arjan ... I commented out odata for now ... it has been producing YSODs